# Login to Azure AD without redirect Microsoftpage

Tags: redirect, authentication, azure-web-app-service, b2b, azure-ad-b2b

I've created a .net application with Azure AD B2B and it works fine, but whenever i try to login it redirect to Microsoft page there it ask for credentials then it come back to my application.

Redirects create user confusion. I want to create the full user experience without the customer leaving our Application. We want to take advantage of secure technologies though.

Is there any way to consume a Azure AD services which help us to login AzureAD without redirecting to Microsoft page?

Please advice!

Comment: Which kind of Azure AD service did you mean? Most of service required the access token which need to get from Azure AD. The Azure AD provides various flow to interact with Azure AD. You can check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios) about the scenarios Azure AD supports.

Comment: Thank you, Actually am completely new to AzureAD, my requirement to create a web application with AzureAD which will not redirect to Microsoft page while login. Instead i need to login to my application without leaving/redirecting. Can I have the steps to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible.

This is for the security consideration. The web app which protected by Azure Active Directory requires to login the users via the page proved by Microsoft. This is how [OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) work. You can refer the flow from below. The **Authorization Server** stands the server provided by Microsoft.

```
 +--------+                               +---------------+
 |        |--(A)- Authorization Request ->|   Resource    |
 |        |                               |     Owner     |
 |        |<-(B)-- Authorization Grant ---|               |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |--(C)-- Authorization Grant -->| Authorization |
 | Client |                               |     Server    |
 |        |<-(D)----- Access Token -------|               |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |--(E)----- Access Token ------>|    Resource   |
 |        |                               |     Server    |
 |        |<-(F)--- Protected Resource ---|               |
 +--------+                               +---------------+
```

If the web app provided the login-page to input the Azure AD account, the site looks like a phishing site which will not be trusted by users.

Comment: Do you think this is still impossible ?